# Return index value of particular row in python dataframe OR list

Tags: python, indexing

Simple indexing question.
I have the following list object named as xlist.
It could also be a df.

```
[        result
 6221  0.974214
 6220  0.973909
 6222  0.973447
 3032  0.973444
 3033  0.973387]
```

I would like to get the index 'value' of a particular row (or is it column as a list?). So for example: I would like to specify row 2 and get 6222.

Am confused as to why this is not straightforward (to me anyway).

Comment: `I have the following list object named as xlist. It could also be a df.` It looks like a list with a dataframe inside it. Sorry, your question is a little unclear.

Comment: add the actual input structure: 1) as a list; 2) as a dataframe

Comment: Thanks. Apologies. It's a list. But my question equally relates to a DataFrame. I don't understand why getting the index value should be different for them.  Here is the input structure: 
   
 **xlist = []
 xlist.append(resdf.nlargest(5,'result'))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of DataFrames, you can do this:

```
#for the first DataFrame in list and the numbers represent the index in those DataFrames
needed_value = xlist[0].reset_index().iloc[1]['index'] #iloc[1] to select 2nd row

print(needed_value)
6222
```

Comment: Thank you that works. Seems very convoluted. I guess I should avoid appending df elements into a list in the first place.